# Where can I find maths papers to read such as proofs of theorems or progress on the twin primes conjecture?

Tags: publishing

I am trying to start reading up on maths proofs, nothing specific, I am just interested to see how people have proved famously difficult maths problems such as fermats last theorem or progress on the twin primes conjecture which are just two I have in mind initially. But the problem is I don't know where to look for papers unless I specifically know the name. If I know the name of a paper, I am able to find it by searching it on google and it will come up but is there like a main place to go to, to browse different mathematical papers?

Comment: I'm afraid "trying to start reading up on math proofs" and "such as fermats last theorem" don't go together well ...

Comment: lol ok so im assuming thats quite advances, thats ok im happy to start small and work my way up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For

> trying to start reading up on maths proofs

I recommend *Proofs from the Book*, which

> ... contains 32 sections (44 in the fifth edition),
>   each devoted to one theorem but often containing multiple proofs and
>   related results. It spans a broad range of mathematical fields: number
>   theory, geometry, analysis, combinatorics and graph theory. Erdős
>   himself made many suggestions for the book, but died before its
>   publication. The book is illustrated by Karl Heinrich Hofmann. It has
>   gone through five editions in English, and has been translated into
>   Persian, French, German, Hungarian, Italian, Japanese, Chinese,
>   Polish, Portuguese, Korean, Turkish, Russian and Spanish.
>
> In November 2017 the American Mathematical Society announced the 2018
>   Leroy P. Steele Prize for Mathematical Exposition to be awarded to
>   Aigner and Ziegler for this book.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proofs_from_THE_BOOK

Comment: ok thanks, would you say that the book would be suitable for my level of understanding which is having just finished doing a level maths and further maths?

Comment: @cooldud The level of understanding required for reading the proofs in the Book varies a lot from proof to proof. I'm pretty sure you would find some too deep, some just right, perhaps a few apparently too easy (but in fact quite clever).

Comment: ok thanks I think I might just have to buy that book, it seems like a good introduction to the field

Comment: @cooldud You're welcome. There's a sixth edition now, but a second hand copy of an earlier one would do just fine.

Answer (score 4):

Wikipedia articles on mathematical topics generally have a References section with links to various papers.  Any halfway decent math text will have a Bibliography.

But don't expect to understand Wiles's proof of Fermat's last theorem if you're a beginner.  It will take years of intensive study to get there.

Comment: +1 I would suggest "Don't expect to understand even the _ideas_ behind Wiles's proof, let alone the proof itself ...".

Comment: ok thanks for the helping

Answer (score 0):

As Robert mentioned it will take lots of time to understand such theorems. You should maybe consider to search for some expository or survey articles about these theorems to get a grasp on how to prove them without understanding every single detail.

Comment: what is an expository

Comment: Expository is an adjective meaning explanatory